# Llamar una función de un archivo cpp desde otro cpp

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt

actualmente programo un proyecto en C++ con el IDE Qt2.8.1 basado en el 5.1.1, El problema es que necesito llamar a una función de un archivo a.cpp desde un archivo b.cpp

El objetivo es realizar una llamada a la función `a::suma( )` **sin necesitar crear una instancia** de la clase `a`.

a.h

```
#ifndef a_H
#define a_H
class a:public QWidget{
explicit a(QWidget *parent = 0);
~a();
public:
void suma(int y, int z);
  };
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include <QDebug>
a::a(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::a){
ui->setupUi(this);
}

a::suma(int y, int z){
int x = y + z;
qDebug() << x;
}
```

b.h

```
#ifndef b_H
#define b_H
class b:public QWidget{
explicit b(QWidget *parent = 0);
~b();
  };
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"
#include <QDebug>
b::b(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::b){
ui->setupUi(this);
}

//Aqui es donde quiero llamar a la función suma. 
//ya intenté con el prototype(creo que no supe aplicarlo)
```

Comment: No queda muy claro. `a:suma( )` *pertenece* a la clase `a`, por lo que no puedes llamarla sin crear una instancia de `a`.

Comment: O, alternativamente, declarar `a:suma( )` como `static`, que también podría ser tu caso. ¿ Quieres llamarla sin necesidad de crear una instancia ?

Comment: Exacto! lo que necesito es mandarla a llamar sin una instancia o si es posible hacer que una conexión al Puerto serial sea accesible desde cualquier archivo .cpp

Comment: Ok. Te he editado la pregunta, espero que no te moleste; ha sido para clarificar lo que pretendes. Ahora escribo una respuesta.

Comment: No te preocupes, y Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como has declarado la clase, no es posible. Los métodos de las clases van *ligados* a instancias de las mismas, y no tienen sentido **sin una instancia** sobre la que invocarlos.

No obstante, y en previsión de estos casos, *C++* provee un mecanismo para ello: la palabra clave `static`.

`static`, aplicado miembros de una clase (pueden ser tanto métodos como variables), permite hacer exactamente lo que pretendes: llamarla **sin** una instancia.

En el caso que expones, sería:

```
// a.h

#ifndef a_H
#define a_H

class a:public QWidget {
  explicit a(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~a();
public:
  static void suma(int y, int z); // <- AQUÍ
};
```

En `a.cpp`, no es necesario cambiar nada:

```
// a.cpp

#include "a.h"
#include <QDebug>

a::a(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::a)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

void a::suma(int y, int z) { // SIN 'static'.
  int x = y + z;
  qDebug() << x;
}
```

Ahora, para *invocar* a la *susodicha* función, lo haríamos así:

```
#include "a.h"

...

a::suma( X, Y );
```

Como ves, es **obligatorio** utilizar el *nombre completo*: `clase::función( )`.

Este tipo de funciones tiene la propiedad de poder acceder a las variables `static` que tenga la propia clase; y **no** se pueden llamar **sobre** una instancia. Justo al contrario de las funciones miembro normales.

Answer (score 1):

Por completar la respuesta de Trauma, decir que los métodos estáticos sólo pueden acceder a atributos estáticos, no tienen el puntero this (y no sé si lo serán las variables de la función que defines como estática).  Recordar que los métodos estáticos sí son accesibles desde una instancia. Dejo un pequeño ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class X {
  int i;
  static int j;
public:
  X(int ii=0):i(ii) {}
  int val() const { return i; }
  static int incr() { return ++j; }
  static int f() { return incr(); }
  int val2() const { return j; }
};

int X::j=10;


int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  X x;
  // Compruebo inicialización correcta (10)
  cout << x.val2() << endl;
  // Voy a incrementarlo (11)
  x.f();
  cout << x.val2() << endl;

  // Creo un nuevo objeto y veo su valor ¿10? ¿11?
  X x2;
  cout << x2.val2() << endl;
  // ¡ tiene el valor 11 ! //
  // Incremento desde este segundo objeto
  x2.f();
  // Veo el valor desde el primer objeto ¡12!
  cout << x.val2() << endl;

  // Todos los objetos de la clase comparten el mismo espacio
  // de memoria del atributo static (de j)

  return 0;
}
```